# How to module.exports at kotlin java like nodejs

Tags: node.js, kotlin

at node js you can create 1 function per 1 file for example

```
// a.js
module.exports = () => "abc";

// b.js
const a = require('./a');
console.log(a()); // abc
```

How can I achieve this at kotlin java
I don't want to create a dot function name, like `a.printAbc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin Java doesn't have module exports. Kotlin JS kinda does, but it works differently. See [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/working-with-modules/working-with-modules.html).

Just import the functions you need. If you have a top-level function, it's imported as `com.some.package.someFunction`. Once it's imported, it's just called like any other function, using `someFunction()` (obviously with arguments if there are any, and handling a return type if there is one)